# Is this an Entity Relationship Diagram or a Class Diagram

Tags: class, uml, erd

Hey basically I am confused between the differences of a class diagram and an ERD. I have created what I thought was an ERD but my flatmate seems to think it is a class diagram. What is it?

[image: Diagram]

Comment: You need to answer a more important question.  Is your model an Object model, and ER model, or a relational model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to the accepted answer, and as @xmojmr noticed as well this is **NOT** a UML diagram, but an Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD).

The most obvious difference is the notation of the connector ends.

Comment: Okay thankyou. I was just confused because each of the entities are tables in my database. I think I may have messed it up a bit and am not sure if this would even be a correct ERD.