# How do I create relationship diagram using plantuml with lines touching the exact field

Tags: plantuml

I have successfully created the ERD with standard notations as per the UML with reference to [ERD Sample](https://plantuml.com/ie-diagram)

But I want to make lines exactly touching the field names as specified in this question [ERD Or UML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111715/is-this-an-entity-relationship-diagram-or-a-class-diagram)

> [image: Diagram]

is there and inbuilt facility available in plantuml or should I simply alter the x y position of the svg element using CSS ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory it can be done using [arrows from/to class members](https://plantuml.com/class-diagram#4829cb0f596c9350). However, it doesn't work as you'd expect:

```
@startuml
' hide the spot
hide circle

' avoid problems with angled crows feet
skinparam linetype ortho

entity "Entity01" as e01 {
  * e1_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  * name : text
  description : text
}

entity "Entity02" as e02 {
  * e2_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  * e1_id : number <<FK>>
  other_details : text
}

entity "Entity03" as e03 {
  * e3_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  e1_id : number <<FK>>
  other_details : text
}

e01 ||.left.o{ e02::e1_id
e01 |o.right.o{ e03::e1_id
@enduml
```

[image: relations to class members]

I'd call it a bug in PlantUML, because the lines end in the center of the entity rather than its edge. You could possibly get it fixed by [reporting it](https://forum.plantuml.net/). However, I doubt you can get a result as nice as the diagram in your question.

Playing around with up/down and `left to right direction` gets me a better result:

```
@startuml
' hide the spot
hide circle

' avoid problems with angled crows feet
skinparam linetype ortho

left to right direction

entity "Entity01" as e01 {
  * e1_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  * name : text
  description : text
}

entity "Entity02" as e02 {
  * e2_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  * e1_id : number <<FK>>
  other_details : text
}

entity "Entity03" as e03 {
  * e3_id : number <<generated>>
  __
  e1_id : number <<FK>>
  other_details : text
}

e01::e1_id ||.up.o{ e02::e1_id
e01::e1_id |o.down.o{ e03::e1_id
@enduml
```

But, again, I doubt this will work with your example. You can try!

[image: left to right direction hack]

Edit: Looking at [this example](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/RPHBRXin38RtF8Kku0jmbNc_toTeQxKP8ECK8tLHP7Btq18a40Yp628Vlfy_xG7yOkoFq_uxtk1D_xRAlgjp__DgrNq_zI-xlp_WTRzhfO-_zhywzF5JdmRqm-xqRw8-GD5Vaxjnkxan6ZSAFqe3dn02gHXec969HiMNvA8o-xebbBD08GOIzyoPLygUyL1ON8c1p3Fth7sgzoVoR2rcE_zncTU8tkQ_Ms_xZjIFbPUqSWbNEaa9TxTCx4MHdph8f_AsKLGIPaoYiJ9ZbW_vzZeNqIk_UQle-VStyUCtMJHk34ynGHoDkgxRxVfG8sBYK15H4L1frAT79I43a28s7bsgGKm9POXLJ5Q86K2EE4Sq8-OEBH4j0R5AXwYbYQYXVaBSMXog-17FTeVgQDN47Ee3wGDXPpb4QXTMTSyT0BHn2sYZ9e_M65o90RGKZ8YIBS10mOWeEG1C50oxA3SPUD6FE_sAVG40), you can see that it's pretty close to the example you stated. I think the key is `left to right direction`.